# JQuery Modify HTML following DIV

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to be able to remove & replace the 4 < br > tags following the < /div > in the following code. The part of the page that I can control begins at the  tag but not the code above. Thanks in advance.

```
<pre>
<div class="pageTitle">
<h1>Unit 2: Week X - Discussion Example</h1>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<style type="text/css">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

- if you're at `div` level.

`$("div.pagetitle").siblings("<br/>,<br>").remove()`

- if you're at `h1` level.

`$("h1").parent().siblings("<br/>,<br>").remove()`

References :

- [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) selector like this:

```
$('div.pageTitle').nextAll('br');
```

or you can use simple [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selector:

```
$('div.pageTitle').next('br')
```

and then loop over this 4.